# Storing view class names on Backbone models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm struggling with a design decision and looking for some feedback. I don't think this question is necessarily specific to Backbone, but that's the framework I'm currently using.

I'm wondering if it's considered bad practice to store the classname of a view as part of a model. For example, let's say you have a parent view with multiple subviews of different types. Each subview contains an edit link, and when that edit link is clicked, the parent view should update it's contents to contain the edit view for that model. I'm using an "event bus" to orchestrate events.

For example:

```
var E = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.apples = options.apples; // Backbone Collection of Apple models
        this.oranges = options.oranges; // Backbone Collection of Orange models
        this.$appleList = this.$('#apples');
        this.$orangeList = this.$('#oranges');
        this.$editScreen = this.$('#edit-screen');

        // listen to edit events for models and render the
        // edit screen for using the appropriate view
        this.listenTo(E, 'edit', this.showEditScreen);
    },

    template: 'templates/parent',

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.model.toJSON());
        this.renderAppleViews();
        this.renderOrangeViews();
    },

    renderAppleViews: function() {
        var view = new AppleListView({collection: this.apples});
        this.$appleList.html(view.render().el);
    },

    renderOrangeViews: function() {
        var view = new OrangeListView({collection: this.oranges});
        this.$orangeList.html(view.render().el);
    },

    // Show the edit screen for a particular model
    showEditScreen: function(model) {
        var view = new window[model.editScreenViewClass]({model: model}):
        this.$editScreen.html(view.render().el);
    }
});
```

`AppleListView` and `OrangeListView` simply loop through their respective collections and append a view to the list.

`AppleListView` adds `AppleItemView`s, and `OrangeListView` adds `OrangeItemView`s. I'm showing the relevant parts of those views below:

```
var AppleItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .edit': 'onEditClick'
    },

    onEditClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        E.trigger('edit', this.model);
    }
});

var OrangeItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .edit': 'onEditClick'
    },

    onEditClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        E.trigger('edit', this.model);
    }
});
```

Here is what the models would look like for this to work:

```
var Apple = Backbone.Model.extend({
    editScreenViewClass: 'AppleEditView'
});

var Orange = Backbone.Model.extend({
    editScreenViewClass: 'OrangeEditView'
});
```

I'm asking if it seems "ok" to store this `editScreenViewClass` on the model. That way I can retrieve it directly from the model passed into the event.

Comment: It seems it would make more sense to store this on the view. For example, adding a `editScreenViewClass` property to the `AppleItemView`.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you're trying to do. Anyway `new window[model.editScreenViewClass]` doesn't seem right. Why can't you store these things in parent view rather than window, and pass the information regarding presentation logic along with the model inside `trigger`..?